# WEBPUSH LARAVEL VAPID

Tags: laravel

Hola tengo un sitio web hecho con laravel. estuve investigando como colocar webpush y me encontre este repositorio https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webpush. lo implemente en mi sitio pero no logro que se muestre las notificaciones ya hice que se registre los datos del usuario en la database pero no entiendo como hacer para q se envie la notificacion a ese usuario en especifico.Alguna de idea de como hacer.

Segun este codigo deberia enviar la notificacion push pero solo ejecuta la opcion notifiable que lo que hace es guardar en la base de datos la notificacion lo que deseo es que se muestre y toWebPush deberia hacerlo pero no lo hace.

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'broadcast', WebPushChannel::class];
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'title' => 'Hello from Laravel!',
        'body' => 'Thank you for using our application.',
        'action_url' => 'https://laravel.com',
        'created' => Carbon::now()->toIso8601String()
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the web push representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @param  mixed  $notification
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\DatabaseMessage
 */
public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
{
    return (new WebPushMessage)
        ->title('Hello from Laravel!')
        ->body('Thank you for using our application.')
        ->action('View app', 'view_app')
        ->data(['id' => $notification->id]);
}
```